# How to get image id into jquery array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Im trying to get all the ids4's from a list of images in a div into an jquery array.
This is the html:

```
<div id = "tdgallerys">
   <img id2="/uploads/ssp/album_2/image_10.jpg" 
        id3="Pic1"  id4="1"
        src="/uploads/ssp/album_2/thumbnails/image_10.jpg"  
        rel="scrollers"/>                  
   <img id2="/uploads/ssp/album_2/image_11.jpg" 
        id3="Pic2"  id4="2"
        src="/uploads/ssp/album_2/thumbnails/image_11.jpg"  
        rel="scrollers"/>                  
   <img id2="/uploads/ssp/album_2/image_12.jpg" 
        id3="Pic3"  id4="3"
        src="/uploads/ssp/album_2/thumbnails/image_12.jpg"  
        rel="scrollers"/>                  
 </div>
```

This is what i am trying:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        var images = new Array();
        var count = 0;
        var id = 0;

        $("[rel='scrollers']").click(function (event) {            
            var dvImages = $('#tdgallerys img').attr('id4');   
            $.each(dvImages , function (i) {
                images.push(dvImages);
                alert(dvImages);
            });
            var desc = $(this).attr('id3');
        });

    });
```

I put the array outside the click function because i need to access the array from another click function later

```
 $("#next").click(function (event) {
            id = id++;
            alert(images[id]);
        });
```

Comment: What's not working with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the collection of image themselves, then push the `id4` attribute into the array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    var images = [];
    var count = 0;
    var id = 0;

    $("[rel='scrollers']").click(function (event) {            
        var dvImages = $('#tdgallerys img');
        $.each(dvImages, function(i) {
            images.push($(this).attr("id4"));
        });
        var desc = $(this).attr('id3');
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/MATq6/1/)

It's worth noting though, that creating your own attributes, such as `id2`, `id3` and `id4` is invalid, and will mean your page will not validate. Instead, look at using the `data` attribute in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
$.each($('#tdgallerys img') , function (i) {
   var id4 = $(this).attr('id4');
   images.push(id4);
});
```

Working example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/PbBxV/1/

You really should be using the [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function within jQuery for storing customer attributes on DOM Elements

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        var images = new Array();
        var count = 0;
        var id = 0;

        $("[rel='scrollers']").click(function (event) {            
            var dvImages = $('#tdgallerys img');   // collection of images
            $.each(dvImages , function (i) {
                images.push(i.attr("id4"));  // for each image push value of id4
                alert(i.attr("id4"));
            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: This will not work .... `i` is not a jquery object - its an `int` see http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the attribute to early. You need to loop over the set of images selected with `$("#tdgallerys img")`, and then get the attribute for each image in that set.

Try this instead:

```
var dvImages = $('#tdgallerys img');   
$.each(dvImages , function (i) {
   images.push($(this).attr("id4"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to walk through each element and to retrieve what you are after (attr id4 in this case):

```
var dvImages = $('#tdgallerys img').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id4');
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xs4h4/